What is a good model for extracting current air density vs altitude data at a given latitude and longitude?
I would like to estimate in real time the air density at a given altitude at a particular position using python. Is there a model I could utilize?

I'm sure this question makes sense to someone who has dealt with Python but that's not me, are you looking for an existing density model or equation that you can use as a model to write a piece of code or an existing piece of code to build upon?
